# The most optimized approach to handle common Webdriver functions library in multiple threads in parallel execution in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, webdriver

I have below class, which has reusable WebDriver functions.

I made all the methods as static since without creating an object ,from my Testcase classes I can access them. Also to keep in mind that " When synchronizing on a static method , the monitor belongs to the class."

```
public  class WebCommand {

    //Go to Url
    public  static void goToUrl(String url,WebDriver driver) {
        driver.get(url);
    }

}
```

So from my Testcase class, I  call this method directly ,using  a
private static ThreadLocal driver = new ThreadLocal();

```
 WebCommand.goToUrl("https://blazedemo.com/login",driver);
```

Since I'm running on multiple threads ,parallelly, to thread safe the methods in  WebCommand  class what should be the best approach?

Even if I make method as non-static, as I know it won't guarantee the thread safety. Any help will be appreciated .

```
  public  void goToUrl(String url,WebDriver driver) {
            driver.get(url);
        }
//Then from TestCase class, call as WebCommand instance -new WebCommand ();
```

Comment: I added a brief answer, but maybe I'm not entirely sure what your concerns about thread safety are. Is there a specific problem you think this code has? If you update the question with more details and reply to my comment, I can update the answer.

Comment: It;'s only passes the parameters so far no problems I  see since I only have few test cases  , thank you for the answer and I upvoted it too.. I'll accept it by waiting for few  answers from community .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this method does not operate on shared data, only passed parameters, it is already thread safe, assuming that the `driver` instance is not shared between threads.